# Using the A tag to carry data dynamically for use in the modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am currently outputting the next 7 days as separate cards with their own card body. In the card header each day will be echoed with a button next to it to add something for this date. Just say it is a todolist. I am trying to create an A tag that once clicked, will give me the value of the date that it is under, to then have this date for use in the modal form (the anchor tag opens up a modal form). How do I achieve this using AJAX/Jquery?

(I am using PHP/MYSQL for the data processing)

Here is my code.

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  

$date = date('Y-m-d'); //today date
$days = array();
for($i =0; $i <= 6; $i++){
  $days[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day", strtotime($date)));
}


foreach($days as $keys) {

$keys = date("l (d-m-y)", strtotime($keys));

echo "<div class='col-lg-6'>
<div class=' card'>
  <div class='card-header'> <h6> $keys <a style='' class='float-right' href='' data-parent='#accordion' data-target='#myModal' data-toggle='modal' > <span class='fa fa-plus'> </span>  </a>
   </h6></div>
  
<div class='card-body'>

</div>
</div>
</div>

 ";


}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What exactly have you tried in jQuery / JS to achieve this ?

Comment: idk how to start

Comment: In that case you could look at some jQuery or JS tutorials first. You can use the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)  as a starting point.